# Constraint Algorithm Optimization C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I can't seem to figure out a way to further optimize a constraint algorithm. So far I've switched to SIMD sse4 vector operations which nearly doubled the performance. I'm hoping there is more performance to squeeze out that I simply don't see.

Here is the algorithm:

```
FVector4 rest(REST_DISTANCE); // Set the constant simd vector outside the loop
FVector4 stiffness(STIFFNESS);

for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
{
    const auto& constraint = Constraints[i];
    auto& position1 = Particle[constraint.first].Position;
    auto& position2 = Particle[constraint.second)].Position;

    for (int j = 0; j < ITERATION_COUNT; j++)
    {
        auto delta = position2 - position1;
        auto distance = delta.norm();

        auto correctionDistance = (distance - rest) / distance;
        auto pCorrection = correctionDistance * delta * stiffness;

        position1 += pCorrection;
        position2 -= pCorrection;
    }
}
```

`Constraints` is an array of a simple struct that holds two unsigned int's, `Particle` is an array of `FParticle` structs which holds three `FVector4` fields and a `Fvector4` simply wraps a `__m128` and provides operators and functions like `norm()` which utilize `_mm_*` intrinsic functions.

Currently the algorithm takes 55 cycles per Constraint per Iteration, this is with `TEST_SIZE` of 150,000 and `ITERATION_COUNT` at 16. I know there is performance to gain from making it parallel but I'm hoping to get more performance out of the single threaded version specifically.

I can post the actual structs if needed.

Thank you.

EDIT:
FVector4 code:

```
struct FVector4
{
    FVector4()
    {}
    explicit FVector4(const __m128& InitData) : Data(InitData)
    {
    }
    explicit FVector4(__m128&& InitData) : Data(InitData)
    {
    }
    explicit FVector4(float InitValue)
    {
        Data = _mm_set_ps1(InitValue);
    }
    explicit FVector4(float X, float Y, float Z, float W = 0.f)
    {
        Data = _mm_setr_ps(X, Y, Z, W);
    }

    __forceinline float& operator[](int index)
    {
        return Data.m128_f32[index];
    }
    __forceinline const float& operator[](int index) const
    {
        return Data.m128_f32[index];
    }
    __forceinline __m128 squaredNorm() const
    {
        return _mm_dp_ps(Data, Data, 0x7F);
    }
    __forceinline __m128 norm() const
    {
        auto sqNorm = squaredNorm();
        return _mm_mul_ps(sqNorm, _mm_rsqrt_ps(sqNorm));
    }
    __forceinline __m128 normalized() const
    {
        auto dp = _mm_dp_ps(Data, Data, 0x7F);
        dp = _mm_rsqrt_ps(dp);
        return _mm_mul_ps(Data, dp);
    }
    __forceinline void normalize()
    {
        Data = normalized();
    }
    __m128 Data;
};
```

Operators as used in the algorithm:

```
__forceinline FVector4 operator-(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_sub_ps(a.Data, b.Data));
}
__forceinline FVector4 operator*(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_mul_ps(a.Data, b.Data));
}
__forceinline FVector4 operator/(const FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    return FVector4(_mm_mul_ps(a.Data, _mm_rcp_ps(b.Data)));
}
__forceinline FVector4& operator+=(FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    a.Data = _mm_add_ps(a.Data, b.Data);
    return a;
}
__forceinline FVector4& operator-=(FVector4& a, const FVector4& b)
{
    a.Data = _mm_sub_ps(a.Data, b.Data);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post this to [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @PaulEvans yup, this looks good for CodeReview, adding some related function may make the question even better though

Comment: @PaulEvans Ah, you're right! Any way to move this there or will I need to just re-post it?

Comment: It's on topic here too. Might as well leave it. But add the relevant code, at least of `norm()`.

Comment: @harold added Code for the relevant FVector4 bits

Comment: OK yes, lots of horizontalness (by crucially relying on `_mm_dp_ps`).. you mentioned the algorithm can be made parallel, how? Not for threading this time, but perhaps that way the work would be divided gives a way to rewrite this vertically.

Comment: @harold To make it parallel I had to group the Constraints so that non of the constraints in the same group share a particle. Since this would create race conditions. After they are grouped, each groups Constraints are then evaluated in parallel. I actually managed to make the velocity calculation step to run vertically but that was much easier since each particle can be evaluated individually. I have not figured out a way to do the same with Constraints.

Comment: Would it leave many empty lanes if you made small groups of up to 4 independent constraints each?

Comment: @harold I don't think so, no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98502/discussion-between-harold-and-nizgtr).